# Does firiing off an indefinite WAITFOR increase the log file size?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, service-broker

In the last release of my app, I added a command that tells it to wait when something arrives in the Service Broker queue

```
WAITFOR (RECEIVE CONVERT(int, message_body) AS Message FROM MyQueue)
```

The DBAs tell me that since the addition, the log sizes have gone through the roof.  Could this be correct?  Or should I be looking elsewhere?

Comment: I think that this maybe a better fit on dba.se

Comment: @Lamak Thanks, I totally forgot that it exists. [Reposted](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30621/does-firiing-off-an-indefinite-waitfor-increase-the-log-file-size).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this in service broker but I assume the same ACID compliance mechanisms would be in play.  It would depend on if it's leaving a transaction open or not in your code.  If it is leaving a transaction open and not committing it, the log will continue to grow until something closes it and only at that point will it finally mark the old areas for re-use.

I haven't rolled service broker in prod yet but the testing/reading I did did not include any WAITFOR. 
Instead, the Server Broker MVPs like Denny Cherry would typically keep querying the queue instead of doing a WAITFOR.

Can you post some of the other code and also tell us why you're using WAITFOR?  Maybe there's something I'm not getting that would be a good use case scenario.  Thanks!

Comment: The reason for `WAITFOR` is the ability to set it and forget it.  My app has many tributaries of data (various apps).  So they just send a message to the queue and my app picks it up.

Also the WAITFOR command does not happen in the context of an explicitly set transaction.  The command gets fired on its own.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Are you able to get more information from your DBA such as which transaction log is actually growing a lot?  Is it from all the DBs writing to the service broker queue or just a few/one?  Is it the DB that is being written to or the ones sending the data?  After that, we can get the LOG_REUSE_WAIT description from that/those databases and find out what is causing it to grow.  THanks!

Comment: I reposted the [question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30621/does-firing-off-an-indefinite-waitfor-increase-the-log-file-size).  Answer is there.

Comment: Excellent!  I was looking to see your TIMEOUT setting in your code and it looks like Remus was also looking away from using WAITFOR.  I'm glad you got it figured out!